# How to show first slide on a jQuery div slider

Tags: jquery, slider

I am working on a slide with links on each slide that trigger the sliding movement. but I cant figure out how to make the first slide appear on load page, so to make it work I had to make the first slide visible and the others hidden, it's not a real fix, is just so I can keep working on it, so I need to change it

here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Paula/XmeGN/10/

Also, I can make it slide to the left instead of the right.

Thank you all for the help!!

HTML

```
<div id="banner_container" style="min-height:160px; clear:both;">

    <div id="banner_wrapper">
    <div class="banner_panel2" id="target1">
        <a href="#target1" class="banner_panel">Target 1</a><br/>
        <a href="#target2" class="banner_panel">Target 2</a><br/>
        <a href="#target3" class="banner_panel">Target 3</a><br/>      
        Target 1
    </div>
    <div class="banner_panel" id="target2">
        <a href="#target1" class="banner_panel">Target 1</a><br/>
        <a href="#target2" class="banner_panel">Target 2</a><br/>
        <a href="#target3" class="banner_panel">Target 3</a><br/> 
        Target 2
    </div>
    <div class="banner_panel" id="target3">
        <a href="#target1" class="banner_panel">Target 1</a><br/>
        <a href="#target2" class="banner_panel">Target 2</a><br/>
        <a href="#target3" class="banner_panel">Target 3</a><br/> 
        Target 3
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

​
javascript:

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $('a.banner_panel').click(function() {
        var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
            $other = $target.siblings('.active');

        if (!$target.hasClass('active')) {
            $other.each(function(index, self) {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.removeClass('active').animate({
                    left: $this.width()
                }, 500);
            });

            $target.addClass('active').show().css({
                left: -($target.width())
            }).animate({
                left: 0
            }, 500);
        }
    });

});​
```

css:

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}


#banner_container {
    width:880px;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#E6E6E6;
    margin:30px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(207,207,207) 22%, rgb(247,247,247)     82%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(207,207,207) 22%, rgb(247,247,247) 82%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(207,207,207) 22%, rgb(247,247,247) 82%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(207,207,207) 22%, rgb(247,247,247) 82%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgb(207,207,207) 22%, rgb(247,247,247) 82%);

    background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left bottom,
    left top,
    color-stop(0.22, rgb(207,207,207)),
    color-stop(0.82, rgb(247,247,247))
);
    border:1px #CCC solid;
    border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    padding:20px 10px 10px 10px;
    overflow:hidden;
    }
    

#banner_wrapper{
    width:890px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:5;
    }

div.banner_panel {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display:none;
}
div.banner_panel2 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
​
```

Comment: Could you explain why this isn't a real fix? Also, the code in  your fiddle is very messy. Its always worth stripping it down to a bare minimum so we can see the core functionality - we don't care about the fancy CSS - that just makes it harder to read!

Comment: Here is the code as clean as possible http://jsfiddle.net/Paula/XmeGN/12/          
It doesnt work because as it is, if you click any slide other than the first one, the slide will show up infront of slide number one, but slide number one never dissapears. I dont know if it makes any sense but If you play the code you will understand what I mean :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add active to target1, i also will show how to remove the panel2

```
 <div id="banner_wrapper">
    <div class="active banner_panel" id="target1">
        <a href="#target1" class="active banner_panel">Target 1</a><br/>
        <a href="#target2" class="banner_panel">Target 2</a><br/>
        <a href="#target3" class="banner_panel">Target 3</a><br/>      
        Target 1
    </div>
    <div class="banner_panel" id="target2">
        <a href="#target1" class="banner_panel">Target 1</a><br/>
        <a href="#target2" class="banner_panel">Target 2</a><br/>
        <a href="#target3" class="banner_panel">Target 3</a><br/> 
        Target 2
    </div>
    <div class="banner_panel" id="target3">
        <a href="#target1" class="banner_panel">Target 1</a><br/>
        <a href="#target2" class="banner_panel">Target 2</a><br/>
        <a href="#target3" class="banner_panel">Target 3</a><br/> 
        Target 3
    </div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $('a.banner_panel').click(function() {
        var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
            $other = $target.siblings('.active');

        if (!$target.hasClass('active')) {
            $other.each(function(index, self) {
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.removeClass('active').animate({
                    left: $this.width()
                }, 500);
            });

            $target.addClass('active').show().css({
                left: -($target.width())
            }).animate({
                left: 0
            }, 500);
        }
    });

});​

$('div.banner_panel.active').show();
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XmeGN/18/

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you so much, totally works, only if i use banner.panel in the first slide it doesnt show any slide, but using your code with banner.panel2 in the first slide works perfectly!

Now, is there a way I can change the js so it slides to the left instead of the right?

Comment: Oh yes it does work, but I wanted to change the sliding movement. right now the slides move to the right and i want them to move to the left

Comment: One more question! is there i way I can make the banner_panel relative instead of absolute? being absolute it doesnt allow its child divs to make the wrapper grow with them :(

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/XmeGN/20/
but i not sure why it changes position of menu inside wrapper

Comment: That js code doesnt really work on my code. the relative div has several floaters maybe thats why. here is the full code http://jsfiddle.net/Paula/BvcDb/

Comment: hm, seems work fine, for IE add ; to last js string, what not work ?

Answer (score 0):

Paula,

- In the HTML, change `class="banner_panel2"` to `class="banner_panel"` and delete the CSS directive for `banner_panel2`.
- (optional) Remove CSS directive `display:none;` from `div.banner_panel {...}`.
- Add `$("div.banner_panel").eq(0).find('a.banner_panel').eq(0).trigger('click');`
   after the click handler definition. Adjust one or both of the `eq(0)` expressions to select any other panel of your choice as the initial panel.

Also, add `e.preventDefault();` at the top of the click handler. This inhibits an undesirable effect when a link is clicked that points to the currently active panel.

Javascript should now look like this :

```
$('a.banner_panel').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
        $other = $target.siblings('.active');

    if (!$target.hasClass('active')) {
        $other.removeClass('active').each(function(index, self) {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.animate({
                left: $this.width()
            }, 500);
        });
        $target.addClass('active').show().css({
            left: -($target.width())
        }).animate({
            left: 0
        }, 500);
    }
});
$("div.banner_panel").eq(0).find('a.banner_panel').eq(0).trigger('click');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XmeGN/14/)**

Users will (probably) see the fly-in effect on page load but maybe that's no bad thing.

Doing it this way ensures that the initial state of the panels is identical to when the user makes a click for him/herself. If, in the future, you change the click handler to do something slightly different then you need to worry less about checking that the HTML/CSS is compatible. Providing everything works fine for user-clicks, then the initial state will also be fine.